# Array in #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
#define MACRO(x) {PORTB=0,PORTC=0,PORTD=0}

MACRO(0); //This would get replaced by PORTB=0;
MACRO(1); //PORTC=0;
MACRO(2); //PORTD=0;
```

I want to create a "macro array". I would pass in an index to it and it would return the right code.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

If it helps, PORTB, PORTC and PORTD are all #defines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done using the preprocessor, but it is arguably ugly.

```
#define MACRO_CASE0 PORTB = 0
#define MACRO_CASE1 PORTC = 0
#define MACRO_CASE2 PORTD = 0

#define MACRO(X) MACRO_CASE##X
```

Also have a look at the [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library.  (It works for both C and C++.)

**Update:** After the discussion with [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) (see below) I feel an obligation to update the answer with an exhortation for new C programmers not to abuse the (powerful but dirty) technique shown above.

If you – as the OP requested – want to *pass in an index to it and it would return the right code*, then you'll need to resort to preprocessor programming.  However, if all you want to do is *execute* different code based on some condition and want this to have no run-time overhead if the condition is a compile-time constant, then the following approach is not only much cleaner but also more flexible as it allows passing run-time values too.

```
/* '#include' this definition in any file where you want to use it. */
static inline void
do_the_right_thing(const int selector)
{
  switch (selector)
    {
   case 0:
      PORTB = 0;
      break;
   case 1:
      PORTC = 0;
      break;
   case 2:
      PORTD = 0;
      break;
   default:
      assert(!"cannot do the right thing: invalid selector");
    }
}
```

Now, in your code, if you write

```
do_the_right_thing(1);  /* selector is a compile-time constant */
```

a decent compiler with appropriate optimizations enabled will generate no overhead compared to using a macro.  However, you can also write

```
do_the_right_thing(rand() % 3);  /* selector is a run-time expression */
```

and the compiler will insert some fast switching code to select the appropriate operation at run-time.

Comment: +1:  When compared with my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26019383/15168), this has the advantage that it can only be used with integer constants for the argument; it has that as a disadvantage too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, but who would want to index an array with anything but an integer?  If you wanted, you could use symbolic names, too.

Comment: It depends on whether you'd ever want to choose the index dynamically: `if (i >= 0 && i <= 2) MACRO(i);` or something like that. If it is a microcontroller, I suspect that you'd not want that, but I don't see that `MACRO(1);` is clearer than `PORTC=0;` in the code — actually, it is a lot less clear to me. But this may, in part, be an artefact of the question. If the code behind the macro were to select one of PORTB, PORTC or PORTD for use on the LHS of an assignment (so usage was `MACRO(1) = 0`), then what I propose would not work — as noted with my 'does not extend or generalize' comment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I hope the example in the question is contrived or else a very bad idea.  You are right about the run-time expression.  I did not think about it because I would only use macros when I really need macros.  (That is, I want to branch *compilation*, not *control flow*.)  If it's about control flow, an inline function with a `switch` would do the trick perfectly well and an optimizing compiler would be able generate the same code if the argument is a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 3):

This would do the task, but it doesn't extend or generalize very gracefully:

```
#define MACRO(x) (((x) == 0) ? PORTB=0 : ((x) == 1) ? PORTC=0 : PORTD=0)
```

Comment: ... and is not very efficient (the OPs code looks like code for some microcontroller).

Comment: @MichaelWalz: What's inefficient?  It's a compile-time constant for the examples shown in the question.  It's not a good idea in the first place, but it does do what is requested.

Comment: Actually it **is** efficient because the compiler optimizes everything. Preprocessor output for macro `MACRO(0)` is `(((0) == 0) ? B=0 : ((0) == 1) ? C=0 : D=0) ;`